# I have a java.lang.NullPointerException when I call my service class

Tags: java, spring, exception, null

I have a problem with m class service on spring mvc when I call m class method it return a java.lang.NullPointerException

```
                // Partie d'importation des Data

                parseData = null;

                Hashtable<String, String> Data = new Hashtable<>();

                Data.put("idName", parseData.ParseidName(saveDirectory + fileName+".txt"));
                Data.put("country", "test");
                Data.put("date", "test");
                Data.put("mncmcc", "test");
                Data.put("pmn", "test");
                Data.put("dns", "test");
                Data.put("mails", "test");
                Data.put("phones", "test");


                //return back to home.jsp
                ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("uploadfile");
                model.addObject("Datas", Data);
                map.addAttribute("Datas", Data);

                 fileNames.add(fileName);
```

My ParsingData service is

```
public interface ParseDataService {

public String ParseidName(String filename);
public String ParseDate(File f);
public String ParseMNCMCC(File f);
public String ParseIP(File f);
public String ParseDNS(File f);
public String ParseContacts(File f);

}
```

And the implementation is

```
@Service("ParseService")
@Transactional
public class ParseServiceImpl implements ParseService {

private static String content;
private static  File raexfile;




@Override
public
  String toTxt(String filename) throws IOException {    

    raexfile =  new File (filename);

    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(raexfile);

    PDFTextStripper s = new PDFTextStripper();

    content = s.getText(document);

       return content;

    }




public ParseServiceImpl() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


}
```

The exception error is a java.lang.NullPointerException I don't know how to initialize my service class :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.roaming.controller.irFileUploadController.crunchifySave(irFileUploadCont    roller.java:78)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62    )
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl    .java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(Invocab    leHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForReque    st(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandle   rMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerA   dapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerA   dapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.hand
```

Comment: Bon jour. Is parseData declared or is NULL?

Comment: Yes I declared before onhe beginning of the class as :  private ParseDataService parseData;

Comment: parseData IS NULL... so parseData.ParseidName throws a NPE.

Comment: How Can I fix it ??